# Where is the php file of single member profile view (BuddyPress)

Tags: php, buddypress

The edit.php file is for single member edit profile page.

And I'm looking for the page that handle single member profile view. So the I can modify the display of user's profile view.

Is there someone knows where is the .php file that I'm looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you are specifically using the `bp-default` theme, then the file you want is:

```
buddypress\bp-templates\bp-legacy\buddypress\members\single\profile\profile-loop.php
```

Comment: Yes, that is what i'm looking for, thx